# How to scroll to a part of a UITextView in TextKit 2 - Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview

I was wondering how to scroll to a specific part of a text in UITextView in **TextKit2**. This approach **won't work in long text**. I'm trying to use a function like this:

```
private func scroll(in textview: UITextView, to substring: String) {
    guard let text = textview.attributedText else {return}
    let str = text.string as NSString
    let substringRange = str.range(of: substring)
    
    if #available(iOS 16, *),
       let textLayoutManager = textview.textLayoutManager,
       let textContentManager = textLayoutManager.textContentManager {
        
        guard let startTextLocation =  textContentManager.location(textContentManager.documentRange.location,
                                                         offsetBy: substringRange.location)
        else {
            return
        }
        let textLayoutFragment = textLayoutManager.textLayoutFragment(for: startTextLocation)
        guard let rect = textLayoutFragment?.layoutFragmentFrame else {
            return
        }
        
        let yOffset = textview.textContainerInset.top + rect.origin.y
        let contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: yOffset)
        
        textview.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: true)
        
    }else {
        // Fallback compatibility
        /// ...
    }
    
}
```

the textLayoutFragment has the following value:

```
▿ Optional<NSTextLayoutFragment>
  - some : NSTextLayoutFragment: 0x11529b0e0 range=1532...1591 layoutState=None frame={}
```

I think in TextKit 2 the fragment won't render due to optimization until it is needed, so in this case, it doesn't have a frame (and also `layoutState=None`).